# Highcharts dual y-axis on the left (column chart)

Tags: highcharts

Can anyone show me jsfiddle example how to make dual y-Axis on the left side of a column chart for high chart (html5)?. P/S i know how to make multiple y-Axis on the right so no need for this

Comment: Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fhgs4cpd/

Comment: This is the perfect answer thank you a gazillion

Comment: You're welcome. I've added this solution as an answer, could you accept and upvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the solution:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
 chart: {
   type: 'column'
  },
  yAxis: [{
   title: {
     text: ''
    }
  }, {}],
  series: [{
   yAxis: 0,
    data: [
      439,
      525,
      571,
      696,
      970,
      119,
      137,
      154
    ]
  }, {
   yAxis: 1,
   data: [
     234,
      123,
      444,
      322,
      543,
      657
    ]
  }],
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**Demo:**

- jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fhgs4cpd